# creating margin with jQuery to position element below absolutely positioned element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to position the bottom element #fooBar 40px below the ul#bar that will have a varying number of li's. I don't want to have to create a class for each element of #fooBar with the appropriate margin.

basically I want to take the height of ul#bar, then add 80px to that number and make that #fooBar's top margin. thanks

Comment: A better example would be nice, I can't understand exactly what you're trying to do that can't be handled with simple CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work?

```
$('#fooBar').css('margin-top', $('ul#bar').height() + 80);
```

Comment: I should add this: where I am logged in now from, that image is blocked by the proxy and I did not see it.

Comment: sorry about the proxy its just hosted at image shack. But I think yours is right, I didn't have the spaces around the "+" sign. thx man.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to absolutely position a container instead of the ul, and setup the elements as you like within it? This way they position themselves without JavaScript ever needing to be involved.

For example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#container{
    position:absolute;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
#foo{
    width:100%;
    background-color:navy;
}
#fooBar{
    width:100%;
    background-color:green;
    margin-top:80px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="foo">Foo</div>
<ul>
<li>Test</li>
<li>Test</li>
</ul>
<div id="fooBar">fooBar</div>
</div>    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah, +1 for Bob. If #bar itself is absolutely positioned, it is completely removed from the flow of the document, so top margin on #fooBar will never have any impact on its position relative to #bar. Wrapping a common parent element around #foo and #fooBar, and absolutely postioning that parent instead of #bar, should do exactly what you want and require no JavaScript.

Comment: No. It has to be absolutely positioned due to layout. Believe me this is the best way to do it. The li's expand out and need to overlay the content to the right of it when they are active.

Comment: Without seeing what you're working with, it's hard to guess why you would absolutely (get it?) have to position it this way, but I think you may be misunderstanding what absolute positioning is for. You are removing it COMPLETELY from the layout, so it can play by its own rules, so any attempts to move elements around or with it are going to be a duct taped mess.

Comment: @Bob. thanks for that, I didn't need a tutorial on positioning, just an answer to my question.

Comment: My apologies, I tend to question statements like 'has to be'. I'm sure you know what you're doing, I've just found when I'm forced to use absolute positioning and javascript libraries to fix a design flaw, I've probably made a more fundamental mistake - not trying to force methodologies on you.

Comment: I avoid all absolutely positioned elements as much as possible. Believe me! Unfortunately this was the easiest solution to get to work across the board. I was just trying to find a more efficient way than adding a separate class with a different margin for each instance based on the number of li's in the absolutely positioned ul.